# Delete Registry Subkey C#

Tags: c#, key, registry

Here's what I have so far, but it just keeps using the catch and the key is never deleted.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
               Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(@"Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Restrictions already removed. Or there was an error.","Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: not trying to delete the value. trying to delete the entire key.
--
EDIT: okay and I have taken the backup thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? Maybe you don't have administrator permission to do so!

Comment: Since you are in a `catch` there is an exception. What does the exception tell you? Tip: You can set the debugger to break when an exception is thrown: Debug > Exceptions... or Ctrl+D, E.

Comment: Ah, yes. The exception says the subkey does not exist. Now, is what I am trying to delete a KEY or SUBKEY?